# How can I parse this query url in ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby, parsing

This is my query command in curl and I can get the results as I expect

```
curl --data "action=search&user=wbt&project=Test&ltoken=&query=build:tables_tempkb status:Analyze" http://xxx.xxx.xxx:8088/review/api
```

However, If I try to query in ruby

```
url = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8088/review/api/?action=search&user=wbt&project=Test&ltoken=&query=build:tables_tempkb status:Analyze"
uri = URI(url)
res = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, 'q' => 'ruby')
```

ruby reports an parsing error below

```
bad URI(is not URI?): http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8088/review/api/?action=search&user=wbt&project=Test&ltoken=&query=build:tables_tempkb status:Analyze
["C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/common.rb:176:in `split'", "C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/common.rb:211:in `parse'", "C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/common.rb:747:in `parse'", "C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/common.rb:996:in `URI'"
```

Could you let me know what's wrong with my ruby script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the space into `%20`. This works:

```
url = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8088/review/api/?action=search&user=wbt&project=Test&ltoken=&query=build:tables_tempkb%20status:Analyze"
uri = URI(url)
```

Alternately, use `+` instead:

```
url = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8088/review/api/?action=search&user=wbt&project=Test&ltoken=&query=build:tables_tempkb+status:Analyze"
uri = URI(url)
```

Both will be decoded in the receiving application as space.

See [Percent Encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

Answer (score 0):

Just encode the URL with `URI.encode` before parsing it:

```
 url = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8088/review/api/?action=search&user=wbt&project=Test&ltoken=&query=build:tables_tempkb status:Analyze"
 uri = URI(URI.encode(url))
```

Comment: I applied it to my script. Thank you @infused